How do I avoid working overtime due to young people's lack of planning without harming them too badly?
A very bright undergraduate student asked me for a letter of recommendation less than a week ago that is due today. She is one of my favorite students and I want to write her a strong letter, however I really have been quite busy the last week, and I am a bit sleep deprived today. I want to do nothing but teach then go home and sleep but I must write a letter.
I really don't want to ruin her application, and I want her to do well because she really is quite a strong student and was a pleasure to have in my class.
I am just going to suffer through it today but how do I avoid this in the future?

If writing one letter of recommendation is pushing you past your limits, then I would look at everything else that is on your plate.

@JonCuster writing a letter with less than a week's notice when I had a tough week already is pushing me past my limits absolutely. I think most faculty would feel similarly.

I think Jon's advice is to focus less on the student's request and more on the tough week pushing you past your limits when thinking about what is making you work overtime.

In the time you wrote this post and checked for answers, you could have written half the letter.

Yes, as @BryanKrause mentioned, the point is you are clearly stretched way too thin already. That is the issue, not this one letter. Nobody can do good work being constantly on the edge of burnout and exhaustion. Write a great letter for the student and ignore a bunch of useless requests.

@JonCuster I agree with the general sentiment, but not all of us work in systems where we can "ignore a bunch of useless requests"...

@YemonChoi - one key principle to being effective is knowing what not to do, or at least not to do now. Let them nag you for a few weeks while you take care of important stuff.

I am surprised by all these responses; either all people here were extremely well organized as junior academics, lightning fast, or they they talk without having reached tenure-track level. As junior academic, even with tightly controlled intake, one is constantly under time pressure (esp. if one protects one's downtime, e.g. weekend). Not saying yes to various seemingly pointless things means that you won't get asked again, also not for things that advance your career. As for a LOR, see my response below.

@JonCuster I am sure you mean well but please look up what the lack of tenure in UKHE means for those of us who work here, as servants of the system. It is sadly the case that it is the useless requests which can often not be ignored without drawing the ire of the customers, or those claiming to represent the customers.

(Insert my usual grumble, as someone who did actually work for a while in a North American system with tenure, that not everywhere in the world is like a North American system with tenure, etc)

@WolfgangBangerth that's a bit harsh, as OP said they're "just going to suffer through it today", indicating that they're not blocked on this post and its responses for writing the letter.

For last minute requests, you can agree to write something but not guarantee to have it done by the deadline - often LoR deadlines are soft or later than the student's deadline.  Of course this depends on what the student needs the letter for.

I would suggest to change the title, it's unnecessary derogatory and presumptive. "Young people's lack of planing": Nothing to do with young people in my experience, requests can come on close notice in academia (how often did supervisors ask for a presentation in a few days/next day...). And nothing per se with "lack of planing". Sometimes, there are good reasons for "short" (it's still a week...) requests, especially in academia IMHO. Overnight e-mails to approve something to meet a deadline to go to a conference: sure, seen it many times. With seniors. So maybe formulate it more general?

Isn't this a general time management question? The task at hand just happens to be related to writing a letter

The time to have said no was when you were asked. As this involves someone's future, you're sort of on the hook to get it done. At least some of the poor planning falls on you.

This is an all-too-familiar situation. I have several pending requests for LORs sitting in my inbox right now, and I have mulled over this issue myself quite a bit over the years. My thoughts:

You can't entirely avoid this, it's simply an aspect of life for any conscientious, well-meaning person working in academia. (The non-conscientious people have it easier; they can simply make it a hard rule to say no to requests that transgress their work-life balance boundaries.)

The consequences for students of a refusal on your part to write a LOR are probably less severe than you imagine. (This is a special case of a general principle I have come to believe in: all of us are less irreplaceable than we imagine ourselves to be...)

You can minimize the effects of this issue on your life by adopting certain practices: first, do allow yourself to say no sometimes. E.g., if you've committed to writing N LORs and the (N+1)-th request pushes you into an uncomfortable personal situation, say no.

Second, when a student writes asking for an LOR and it's not a last-minute request, give them a clear list of your expectations of what they need to do and when they need to do it in order to give you time to perform the task. Keep a template email lying around where you list those expectations and can reuse when LOR requests come in. For example: "please send me a list of programs you're applying to and their application deadlines. Also include your CV, grade transcript [etc], and send me those materials no later than 3 weeks before the earliest application deadline."
Students may be disorganized, but having hard constraints and clear expectations can often motivate them to get their acts together.

Also, recognize that this issue only affects our lives for a short part of the year (October and November usually in North America). So, while it's a fact of life, being sub-optimally busy during certain parts of the year is something that academics generally get used to and accept; when you consider that academia also gives you other parts of the year during which you are relatively un-busy (in some cases also sub-optimally, but in a more fun way), it's not a bad deal overall...



Your fourth bullet is also good idea in that it teaches the student to be effective and organized in professional communications, already at the first contact.

I very much disagree with the wording of the first bullet point. Setting work-life balance boundaries is extremely healthy and important, and respecting those boundaries does not at all contradict conscientiousness.

@GregMartin I am describing precisely a scenario where conscientiousness and firm work-life boundaries stand in conflict with each other. Since you disagree, what’s your advice to OP (assuming they belong to the class of conscientious people) in this situation?

You won't avoid it in the future. You will always get that one extra request, if not by your student, then by your head of department who needs a last-minute input, your colleague that finds that one proposal deadline in two days, etc.
Many people suggest to just say no to taking things on. This is a common oversimplification and it needs to be considered judiciously. Saying no is particularly difficult for a junior academic.
You can deny the student, but you might deprive them of a vital career opportunity. You can may say no the head of department, but that's costing you political capital. You can say no to your colleague and, next time, they will ask someone else to join their project.
As consequence, you need to evaluate if that's a cost you are ready to bear. As you become more senior, this may be easier to do. However, as long as you are in a junior phase of your career, you may be reluctant to do so, since you still need to build up your reputation.
One part of the response is, partly, to keep a few buffers in your schedule, as other answers suggest. But, I'll be frank, that may simply not be possible. No matter how much the mantra of work/life balance is repeated today - the life of an academic, especially a junior one, has extremely busy stretches. Not all the time, and there also is a lot of flexibility; but, let's face it, over phases, you may be drastically oversubscribed. It's just the way it is.
Therefore, you need to look to alternative trade-offs, and the most important one is to learn to work to the available time slot and trade in quality for time.
Note that, with your researcher hat on, you want to ensure the highest degree of quality for your scientific work, especially the carrying out of the research and the write-up of the papers. These require (ideally) the highest degree of clean-up, consolidation and polishedness and can in general not be rushed. Here, you need to take your time and give every detail its due respect.
For non-scientific routine work, however, it is often well possible to accept an effective less-than-perfect approach.
For a LOR, for instance, you can hack one out by writing how you met the student, your experience with them, a general evaluation based on this evidence, and your conclusions about whether they are suitable for the job. A pithy and well-written 3-4 paragraphs LOR is, for a talented undergrad, a perfectly sufficient space to help them into a strong program. It's far easier to write a LOR for a very bright student than for a generally support-worthy, but not quite as strong one.
With a bit of experience, a strong LOR can be written well in 20-30 minutes (without AI!). But you need to accept that it will probably not be as powerful a LOR as you could devise if you had 2 or 3 hours. That's the price that the student needs to pay for coming in the last minute; not because you wish that price to be paid, but simply by force of the circumstances.
But at the same time, knowing you can trade this off gives you the elasticity that you need to add this one more thing into your packed plate.

There is nothing you can do to avoid this situation in the future, because the situation wasn't of your making. You can either refuse a last-minute request (likely harming the student's chances) or agree to it and take on extra work with a quick turnaround time. Either choice would have been understandable here.
Advice for today: don't stay up all night. Take an hour or two before bed and write the best letter you can in that time. It likely won't be as strong a letter as it would be if you had more time, but that's not your fault.

That second paragraph could also be a good advice for the future: instead of declining a "last-minute" request right away, they might tell the student they are willing to write a letter, but given the short timeframe and the fact that it's a busy week, it might not be as strong as it could possibly be if OP had more time. The student can then decide if they want this not-so-strong letter or rather keep asking other professors that might be less busy.

Probably you can't, completely. You could let your students in general know that you need, say, at least two weeks. You could ask them to give you an idea of what they might think it important to mention.
But, the student might even have valid reasons for a late ask.
Some people ask for a draft written by the student. I only mention, but don't recommend that.
The other way to do this in the future is to start early/immediately on such a request, just by jotting notes somewhere on what to include. It is harder if you start late, especially if you are overworked.

There are countries where a draft by the student (which is then edited by the prof) used to be accepted, e.g. Germany. In the Anglo-Saxon space, I have never seen it, so whether it is acceptable or not will heavily depend on location. In Germany, people used to undersell themselves, so the prof typically has to bump it up, maybe that's why it works. It's probably not working so well in this direction in the US ;-) My personal view is that the best references are the ones that are never seen and expected to be seen by the candidate.

I asked a somewhat similar question on Interpersonal SE five months ago and managed to find a workable solution. Applying it to your case, I would recommend the following:
(1) Inform your students in advance that if any of them wants a LoR from you in the future, they will need to ask you a certain amount of time in advance. This is especially important when you supervise a student working on a research project with you, as such students are very likely to ask for a LoR later on. This measure will reduce the number of last-minute requests and give you a good reason to decline them.
(2) Just say no to last-minute requests if you feel that the student isn’t particularly bright or can obtain a LoR from someone else without significantly affecting their application. Don’t argue or over-explain; simply say something like:

I'm sorry, but I absolutely can't. I'm extremely overburdened this
week. I really can't help you with your application this time, but I'm
happy to support future applications. Just remember, as I've warned
before, LoR requests need to be made at least three weeks in advance
so I can fit them into my schedule.

(3) Consider offering a compromise for bright students who make last-minute requests:

Look, I’m happy to support you, but you made your request very late.
Аs I've warned before, LoR requests need to be made at least three
weeks in advance so I can fit them into my schedule. I'm currently
very overburdened, so I can only manage a short LoR this time. If you
need a longer, more impressive LoR, you could help by providing a
draft. Include any details you think might strengthen your case, and
I'll use the draft to write a strong LoR within my time constraints.

Please note that while this last suggestion is common practice in some countries, it might be considered academic misconduct in others, so use it with caution.

Huh. Academic misconduct?  I (N American) find that very surprising, but would be happy to learn.  Can you flesh that part of the answer out a little bit?

@BenBolker I think that this refers to the fact that some cultures do not accept a pre-conceived draft of a LOR by the students that is later edited by the referee and consider this ethically questionable. Others, like Germany, do accept that as a model.

I see: it's the "providing a draft" part that's problematic.

I think you are approaching this the wrong way. Getting an unexpected student request isn’t the real problem, this is:

[…] I really have been quite busy the last week, and I am a bit sleep deprived today. I want to do nothing but teach then go home and sleep […]

It’s not this letter that makes your plate spill over because frankly it already has. If you have an entire week and can’t find the time to write one letter then the problem is the week, not the letter.
And taking a wild guess here: probably the week before, and the week before, and the week before, and …
Now there are a lot of self help books out there and I won’t repeat any of them, but realise that a day has only 24h, a week has only 7 days, and your life has only about 4000 weeks. You literally can’t do everything you want to do, let alone what you think you should do. So decide for yourself what you actually want to spend time on.
If that includes supporting good students (and I hope it does) then acknowledge, up front, that this takes time. If there is one thing you can expect from students it’s the unexpected, so block some time for that! This can be a few hours every week, or if you are better at predicting the unpredictable perhaps a few more hours during specific seasons.
And should you ever find that you have blocked more time than you need - well, go get some sleep!

Yes, prioritize. Eventually, you'll be receiving too many requests for your time, not all of which can be completed "by schedule". And, in my experience, students do very often procrastinate, and/or misjudge the time it takes to write a letter of recommendation, etc. Yes, I am always a bit stressed by last-minute requests, but I don't hold it against the students, any more than I hold grudges to young kids who do dubious things because they don't know any better... :)

"And taking a wild guess here: probably the week before, and the week before, and the week before" That's an ASSumption. It's crunch time in the US: midterm season, particularly for those on quarters (trimester), and it often rolls right into holidays (Thanksgiving), finals, and grad school deadlines. Further, the US Government's fiscal year starts October 1: there was a rush for funders to spend money before that, and now everything is gearing up with new money. In research, many facilities are effectively shut down after the first week of December-mid Jan for service, so it's a final push.

@user71659 Yes, it’s an assumption - that’s why I wrote "wild guess". Since the question isn’t just about the specific occurrence but the general behaviour of student requests being late, I feel it’s safe to assume this is also a general problem for the OP and not restricted to any one specific season. Regardless, it doesn’t change the advice: No matter if they need to set aside time tentatively the entire year, for a month, for a week or even for a day, they should set aside time if they expect unexpected requests that they want to handle.

I've had professors ask me to draft my own letter and send it to them. The first time it happened I was scandalized, but I later learned it's a common practice.
Not that you just sign what they wrote, but it gives you an idea of what needs to be covered, and a place to start. Also, it requires them to put forth a comparable level of effort to what they're asking from you--that will help you gauge how important it actually is to them.

+1 This is far and away the best solution. Letting the student prepare the initial draft is indeed a common and acceptable practice. It's also an opportunity for the student to gently remind the advisor of their accomplishments and to invest their own time into their own application process.

Short Term Solution: Cheat... I mean, Use Generative AI
Ask ChatGPT or a similar GAI to write it for you.  Instead of writing out a whole letter, just write a short prompt outlining the student's qualities you want highlighted. It should be something like this:
"I am <my-name>, a professor at <my-university>.  Write me a formal letter of recommendation for my student <their-name> who is applying to <their-grad-school>.
The students best qualities are: <strength-1>, <strength-2>, and <strength-3>."
Then you just need to proofread and send.  ALWAYS PROOFREAD This will give you a nice thought out sounding recommendation letter, but only take 2-5 minutes instead of however long you would normally spend having to choose each word carefully.  While I'm not the biggest fan of using Generative AI for most things, this is exactly the kind of formality writing that it excels at.  Plus, if you're truly back against a deadline and not of sound mind to make it work, I'm sure your student would prefer this to nothing at all, or something riddled with mistakes because you could not give it the focus it deserves.
The Long Term Solution: Still cheat, but make it more personal
GAIs are trainable.  If you have more than 5 sleep deprived minutes to dedicate to problem, you can start by uploading sample letters of recommendation that you have written in the past, and tell ChatGPT to use them as style guides.  Then when you prompt it to generate new letters of recommendation based on the previous letters. It will then mirror your tone and speech patterns as a guide for what sort of language choices it should be using when it writes future letters on your behalf so that they sound more like you.
While I know some people really hate GAIs on principle and find that they can be very impersonal when used without intention, when you train them on your own writing, you are eliminating all the mental load of doing the same thing over and over you do every time you write one and focus instead on just the things that make this one student exemplarily.
